# Из Firestorage получаю ссылки что бы отобразить картинки на сайте, не все так гладко

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Получаю ссылки из Firebase Storage, Для отображения их на сайте в карточках (я не так давно начал изучать JS). Из базы данных я получаю массив, и когда вытаскиваю ссылки и пушу в массив, они создают 2 новых массива для каждой ссылки. Подскажите как сделать так что бы они были в одном массиве.

```
    //state каталог для товаров
    const [catalogItem, setCatalogItem] = useState([])
    const [url, setUrl] = useState([])

    // вытягиваем url с картинок из firebase storage
    const displayImage = async (item) => {
        await getDownloadURL(item)
            .then(getUrl => {
                const urlArr = []
                urlArr.push(getUrl)
                console.log(urlArr)
            })

    }
```

[image: То что выдает в консоли браузера]

```
// получаем элементы из firebase storage и вызываем функцию displayImage
    useEffect(async function getImageStorage() {
        const storage = getStorage()
        const listRef = ref(storage, 'images/')
        await list(listRef)
            .then(response => {
                const urlObj = response.items
                console.log(urlObj)
                for(let i =0; i < urlObj.length; i++){
                    displayImage(urlObj[i])
                }
            })
    }, [setUrl])
```

Comment: Есть на Гитхабе проект, или в песочнице ?

Comment: Нет, я не выкладывал, учусь пока, и если четно я не знаю что такое песочница) И как туда его ставить

Comment: суть в том, я получаю массив, как с данных массива с каждого элемента получаю ссылки, все эти ссылки прилетают разом и когда я их пушу в пустой массив, каждый из этих ссылок создает  новый массив, а хотелось бы что бы было в одном массиве, для дальнейшей итерации.

Comment: Добавь больше кода, не понятно как компоненты организованы + образец данных которые приходят с сервера.

Comment: Образец данных я вставил тут, то что приходит массив до и после

Comment: https://github.com/TimurZairov/kutec-uz Это ссылка на репозиторий, проект там лежит